# What does ( mean after a fat arrow function in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add an if statement to a function and am getting syntax errors.  Here's the original function `test` using the fat arrow syntax that works.  I think I'm misunderstanding what the `(` around the return object means in line 2.  I'm used to seeing `{` but not sure what a `(` means.

```
var foo = {
    test: (state, action) => (  // does this paranthesis create a block around the function? or does it mean something else?
      {
        isFetching: false,
      }
    )
}
```

However I get a syntax error when I try to add an if statement, what does the parenthesis mean in this case - is it declaring the body of a function declared with a fat arrow?

The following gives a syntax error:

```
var foo = {
    test: (state, action) => (
      if (action.payload) { 
        return { isFetching:false } ;
      } else {
        return { isFetching: true };
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: tl;dr, it means that it's an expression, not a block, `()=>({})` is a function that returns an object literal.

Comment: ah yes, that other duplicate question answers it.